# update xml file within doc library using jquery ajax

Tags: document-library, jquery, xml, ajax

I can read values from xml files that are posted within a document library using jquery ajax, but can I update those values then save/post them back into the document. i.e. can I update the contents of an xml file within a document library from a page using the jquery ajax (or any other jquery method for that matter) style approach?

appreciated as always guys!